# Create a global function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to create a global function where I can use it anywhere inside a `.js` file.

We have more than 50 javascript files joined together and inside each files I want to be able to use this library anywhere.

Localized.js

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
        // only CommonJS-like enviroments that support module.exports,
        // like Node.
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        // Browser globals (root is window)
        if (typeof Localized !== 'undefined') {
            throw 'Localized" already in use';
        }

        root.Localized = factory();
    }
}(this, function () {

  var _strings,
      _readyCallback,
      _isReady = false,
      _requestedStrings = false;

  function ready( data ) {
     _readyCallback = _readyCallback || function(){};

    function domReady() {
      // If the DOM isn't ready yet, repeat when it is
      if ( document.readyState !== "complete" ) {
        document.onreadystatechange = domReady;
        return;
      }
      document.onreadystatechange = null;
      _strings = data;
      _isReady = true;
      _readyCallback();
    }

    domReady();
  }

  // Get the current lang from the document's HTML element, which the
  // server set when the page was first rendered. This saves us having
  // to pass extra locale info around on the URL.
  function getCurrentLang() {
    var html = document.querySelector( "html" );
    return html && html.lang ? html.lang : "en-US";
  }

  var Localized = {
    get: function( key ) {
      if ( !_strings ) {
        console.error( "[goggles.webmaker.org] Error: string catalog not found." );
        return "";
      }
      return ( _strings[ key ] || "" );
    },

    getCurrentLang: getCurrentLang,

    // Localized strings are ready
    ready: function( cb ) {
      if ( !_requestedStrings ) {
        _requestedStrings = true;
        _readyCallback = cb;

        function onload( data ) {
          ready( data );
        }
        onload.error = console.log;

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/strings/' + getCurrentLang() + '?bust=' + Date.now(), false);
        xhr.send(null);
        if (xhr.status !== 200) {
          err = new Error(id + ' HTTP status: ' + status);
          err.xhr = xhr;
          onload.error(err);
          return;
        }
        onload(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
      };
      if ( _isReady ) {
        _readyCallback();
      }
    },

    isReady: function() {
      return !!_isReady;
    }
  };
  return Localized;
}));
```

So I want to be able to go into any of the **50** files and do `Localized.get("something");`
But then I don't even have the `Localized` object available in the **web console**. For example if you have `jQuery` you can do `$` in the web console and you can do anything there.

Comment: Inside your module do something like `window.Localized = Localized` to make the module available globally.

Comment: Where are you running this from? I would expect it to be global because of `root.Localized = factory();`. If it's not, then this `this` you're passing is not the global object. Are you running that from inside another function, maybe an IIFE or a document.ready handler?

Comment: You mentioned you want to replicate how jQuery does it, so why not look at the jQuery source and see for yourself? If I remember correctly it's similar to what Frank said

Comment: Look, it's available globally when I tried in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GP3TG/

Comment: First of all, the file containing this function should be the in the header tag before any other script, and this function could simply return `window.Localized = (root.Localized = factory()); `. Second, you have to be sure that you do not override the variable `window` anywhere before the `return`.

Comment: @bfavaretto but how do I use that?

Comment: Use what? I just pasted your code into jsfiddle, and it seems to work?

Comment: @bfavaretto yeah that was true it is accessible! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that my javascript is globally defined and accessible everywhere within the file that is included and it can be call from the **console** as well except I have to initialize that by doing **`Localized.ready(function(){});`** then I can get it to work.

So if anyone is looking to create their own global function and make it standard they can follow this way.

*[amdWeb.js](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/amdWeb.js)* is what I use as a standard to create global function.

Comment: the link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever looked at the Three.js global function? It's super easy to understand!

```js
(function (global, factory) {
 typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
 typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
 (factory((global.THREE = global.THREE || {})));
}(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';
```

Comment: Could you please explain? For me, it's hard to understand.